# Explicit class import within same package

Tags: java, package

A friend of mine recently ran into a problem where he instantiated a class within another class that was in the same package, but the code would not compile. After explicitly importing the class: `import Baz.Bar;` everything was fine. I have searched Google for documentation on this, but have come up dry.
If anyone could provide a reference to why an explicit import is needed that would be great, thanks.

## Example of explicit import:

### Foo.java

```
package Baz;
import Baz.Bar;

public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    new Bar();
  }
}
```

### Bar.java

```
package Baz;

public class Bar {
  public Bar() {}
}
```

Comment: Is this the exact code that has been tested?

Comment: did Bar originally conflict with another already imported class (possibly from `java.lang` or through a `foo.*` import)?

Comment: What @jtahlborn said, or also inner classes.

Comment: I added Bar for clarity. There were no conflicts, because there were no other classes with the same name.

Comment: what was the _actual_ name of Bar?

Comment: No, but the names were very unique.